# When to use List View

Tags: android, performance, listview

Should I use List View if I will be placing 10 Linear Layouts, each with 2 Text Views ? There will always bet only 10, never more or less. 
Is using so much layouts bad for performance ? Will List View be better ?

Comment: Do you need an Adapter to manipulate the data? Better than using what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are absolutely 100% certain that there will always be just ten, you don't need a `ListView`. Otherwise, use `ListView` (or better yet, `RecyclerView`).

There's no performance issues if you use multiple layouts manually - this is what a `ListView` will essentially do anyway. Of course, if the number of items is huge, a `RecyclerView` will do the best job performance-wise since it will recycle the views.

Answer (score 1):

ListView extends AdapterView, which is made for dynamic content, since you will always have 10 views inside, you should use a LinearLayout and declare it all with it's children in an XML.